# Ruby, stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class BookPrice
  attr_accessor :price
  def initialize(price)
    @price = price
  end

  def price_in_cents
    Integer(price*100 + 0.5)
  end
end

b = BookPrice.new(2.20)
puts b.price_in_cents
```

This all works well and produces 220. But when I replace the second line attr_accessor :price with:

```
def price
  @price = price
end
```

I get stack level too deep (SystemStackError) error. What's going on? I know I can replace Integer(price*100 + 0.5) with @price instead of the method call price, but I want to keep it the way it is for OOP reasons. How can I make this code work the way it is without attr_accessor?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your below code

```
def price
  @price = price # <~~ method name you just defined with `def` keyword.
end
```

Creates never stopable recursion,.

> How can I make this code work the way it is without attr_accessor?

You need to write as

```
def price=(price)
  @price = price
end
def price
  @price 
end
```

Comment: `def price=(price)` is also fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing I'll use def price=(new_price) for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do:

```
@price = self.price
```

to differentiate between your object attribute `price` and your method parameter `price`.

Answer (score 2):

One general reason this can happen is if you have some method that calls itself recursively (i.e. calls itself inside itself, which causes an infinite loop).

That's the problem I had that led to the error message.

In your case that's what's happening here:

```rb
def price
  @price = price
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`read_attribute` is what you are looking for

```
def price 
  @price = read_attribute(:price)
end
```