# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) when deleting a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack-overflow

I'm getting a Stack Overflow error when deleting a record:

> SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
>     app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'

I found another System Stack Error related to ruby, but I did not completly get how to fix it since my problem is slightly different.

It is here: [Ruby, stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082772/ruby-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)

This is the method, and the second line is causing the error:

```
def destroy
@order = Order.find(params[:id]).destroy
flash.now[:success] = true
flash.now[:success_title] = "¡Orden eliminada!"
flash.now[:succes_message] = "La orden #{@order.id} fue eliminada."
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to orders_path}
  format.js {}
end
```

What can I change to fix this issue?

Comment: Which line is 18? We cannot tell from the code you posted since it is only the single action. Can you post the entire file?

Comment: Does any of your associations have `dependent: :destroy` ? This will also raise a stack level too deep error.

Comment: @kcdragon line 18 is def destroy

Comment: @codyeatworld they do `order` has `order_items` and they are dependent.

Comment: I had `dependent: :destroy` on both sides, eliminated the `order_items` one and the method was called successfully, if you write the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack level too deep error occurs when you try to delete a record with relationships that declare `dependent: :destroy` linking back to each other.

Example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Removing `dependent: :destroy` from the Item assocation should resolve the circular error/stack level too deep.

Comment: Brilliant. I was having a hard time getting wtf is going on but then I read once again closely and that was it. Thanks!