# How use dependent: destroy without causing infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models. Model one with `belongs_to :model_two` and model two with `has_one :model_one`. They both have `dependent: :destroy`

When I try `self.model_one = nil` it goes into infinite loop.

```
SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
```

If I change the association in model one to `dependent: :delete`, it works ok, but there is high probability it'll be skipping some hooks in model by doing direct delete in DB.

How do I use `dependent: :destroy` without causing the loop?

Comment: Does this answer help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39091508/4414956

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in Rails 4. You can't use `dependent: :destroy` on both sides of the assocation as it causes an infinite loop. You need to remove the `dependent: :destroy` option on one side of the association.

[Bi-directional `dependent: :destroy` support](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/12/rails-5-supports-bi-directional-destroy-dependency) was added in Rails 5 and your best bet if you need this functionality is to upgrade your application as it was not backported.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run `dependent: :destroy` on both the models. It's enough to run on a model that has `has_many :model_one`.

Ex:

```rb
## User Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
end

## Article model
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The above code says when a particular user is deleted, also delete all the articles that the user created. That's it.

What your code is doing is, when a user is deleted, delete all the articles that the user deleted, then again jumps to deleting the user and so on..

Comment: There are still cases where you would want a bi-directional `dependent: :destroy` that runs your callbacks no matter which side of the relation you have called destroy on.

Comment: As I wrote, I don't have `has_many` side. I have `belongs_to` and `has_one` sides. I'll try to update the question with example.